# In V8 why does a preallocated array consume less memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, v8

Consider the following two alternatives:

```
  const mb_before = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  const n = 15849;
  const o = 115;
  const entries = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const subarr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < o; j++) {
      subarr.push(Math.random());
    }
    entries.push(subarr);
  }
  const mb_after = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  console.log('arr using ' + (mb_after - mb_before) + ' megabyte');
  // arr using 15.110992431640625 megabyte
```

and

```
  const mb_before = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  const n = 15849;
  const o = 115;
  const entries = new Array(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const subarr = new Array(o);
    for (var j = 0; j < o; j++) {
      subarr[j] = Math.random();
    }
    entries[i] = subarr;
  }
  const mb_after = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  console.log('arr using ' + (mb_after - mb_before) + ' megabyte');
  // arr using 12.118911743164062 megabyte
```

From my understanding the two arrays' size should be identical, only the way they were instantiated differs. How can it be explained that the resulting memory usage is consistently different?

Comment: In a word? Optimization.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the correction; would still like to know how one can optimize the persistence of the amount of data in different ways based on the method that the array was instantiated

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean my deleted comment as a *correction*, just as a collegial joke. Sorry if that didn't come across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the way array memory is allocated. When you instantiate an array giving it a specific size as you are in the second example, it will allocate that memory.

When you grow the array it will allocate a small amount of extra space to handle growth and then as you grow the array the additional memory allocations will get bigger. This results in extra free space in the first example.

Comment: (V8 developer here) This is correct. When you use the `Array(n)` constructor, V8 can allocate exactly as much space as you'll need. When you create an empty Array (using `[]` or `new Array()`) and keep adding elements to it, V8 grows the backing store in chunks, so at the time you stop adding elements, there might still be some unused pre-allocated backing store.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this surprising at all. Although standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)*, JavaScript engines default to optimization: Treating them as though they were really arrays when they can.

In your first example, V8 doesn't know how big each of the arrays is going to get — it just keeps growing, and in order to treat it as an optimized array (rather than an object with special properties), V8 has to keep reallocating and copying to make it bigger periodically. So it's not surprising that the most recent proactive allocation left a lot of extra room in case it kept growing.

In your second example, you've given V8 a big old clue in advance of how big you intend to make the array. So it's reasonable that V8 would use that information to optimize the allocation it does for the underlying true array.

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*